# Cypress visit won't visit desired site

Tags: javascript, cypress, cucumberjs

I want to test a given page (http://localhost:4200/#/index/tools).
In Cucumber I have

```
  Given user navigates to tools
    Then a flowchart is displayed
```

In Cypress I have

```js
import { Given, When, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';

Given('user navigates to tools', () => {
  cy.viewport(1532, 772);
  cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/#/index/tools');
});

Then('a flowchart is displayed', () => {
  cy.get('.flowchart').should('be.visible');
});
```

Cypress isn't getting the `.flowchart` (despite existing) because it doesn't go to `/tools`. It stays at `/home`, a page visited previously.

Why isn't it visiting the correct page?

I also tried with

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/#/index/tools').wait();
```

and

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/#/index/home');
cy.get('#navbar-dropdown > a').click();
cy.get('#tools-link').click();
```

and either works.

Comment: possible reason for this issue is that Cypress is asynchronous, and the cy.visit() command might not have completed before the next step is executed. To ensure that Cypress waits for the page to load before proceeding to the next step, you can use the cy.wait() command after cy.visit()

Comment: I've already tried this. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I can't leave a comment - here are a couple ideas:

1. If the page you want to test has a different origin (including localhost on a different port), you may want to look into [`cy.origin`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin). It could be worthwhile to learn a little about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in the process.
2. A non-answer: I ran into a similar issue before with Cypress, and after a lot of getting nowhere, I ultimately switched to [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/), after which I was able to visit external sites without issue.